# How to return the function output value and store it into a string in groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to get the output value from one function and store it into the string. Below is my code where i'm trying to return 'productURl' from getUrl function and store it into product from String getProduct

```
String getProduct(def request, productDetails) {
  String product
  if (productDetails) {
    def a = productDetails.details
       if (a == null) {
         getUrl(request)
        } 
       else {
        product = www.amazaon.com / sampleProduct
        }
  } else {
    getUrl(request)
}
// How to get the productURL output from getUrl function here    
   product
}

//New function
 def getUrl(request) {
    def productURL
    def session = request ? .getSession(false)
    productURL = session ? .product

       if (!productURL) {
        // code for getting the product URl
        }


   //this is the output value i want to return
     productURL
   }
```

Comment: `product = getUrl(request)` should do. Is there any issue?

Comment: when i did that product value is returning null in getProduct function

Comment: `getUrl` method does not look legitimate. Number of opening and closing braces do not match. Try to come up with a simple groovy script portraying this scenario.